# Microsoft Graph: How to get the e-mail address of an Outlook task's assignee?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Using Outlook I assign a task to user *Romeo Reader*:

[image]

I request task updates:

[image]

Thus the task remains in my task list as well.

I now use Microsoft Graph to receive a list of all my tasks. The task I assigned to Romeo Reader is included in this list. The `assignedTo` property is set to the name *Romeo Reader* identifying this task as having been assigned:

[image]

Note: This is a plain string property containing the user's display name.

How do I get more information about this user I assigned the task to? I need his e-mail address. Or some other info to get his user profile (email, picture etc.). But this seems not possible since the display name most likely is not unique.

How do I get an identifier for this user that I assigned the task to (using Microsoft Graph)?

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is that Microsoft Graph doesn't expose this information directly. What you see is what you get. [outlookTask resource type](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/outlooktask).

What might work for at least some of the cases is doing a [relevant people search](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_people) with the value of the `assignedTo` property:

```
GET /me/people?$search="Romeo Reader"
```

I realize this isn't 100% reliable, but it's the best that can be done with the current state of the Outlook Tasks stuff in Graph. I'd recommend giving feedback on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com).