# Microsoft Graph api returns tasks with empty assigned fields

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

While listing my tasks using the endpoints `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/taskFolders/[id]/tasks` the tasks always have the `assignedTo` field empty, even though they are assigned to a user. This includes the Graph Explorer which also lists the task without the field populated. The Microsoft graph beta documentation has the `assignedTo` field listed as an expected response field, and refers to the normal outlookTask page when describing the field further.

The tasks are located in a shared folder, and will correctly show up in the official To-do web/mobile applications as being assigned to a user. This is also where I made the original user assignments. I have so far only tried listing tasks assigned to the currently logged in user (ie. the user making the graph request), however I would still expect this to work.

Does anyone know if this is a limitation with the current beta graph api, or if I'm making some incorrect assumptions in how I'm requesting the data? Is it maybe an issue with assigning a user in To-do as opposed to somewhere in the old Outlook tasks UI?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft Graph: How to get the e-mail address of an Outlook task's assignee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416164/microsoft-graph-how-to-get-the-e-mail-address-of-an-outlook-tasks-assignee/51424688#51424688) and https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6850#event-2967878283 it seems the `assignedTo` field is only populated when using the Microsoft Outlook Desktop client and not Microsoft To Do.